# Hidden surface removing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cloud, hidden, points, surface

I have a representation of 3D object as a a) cloud point and b) triangle mesh
My goal is to rotate this object and than obtain a surface which is visible from one specific view. 
Then I would remove the points which are not visible from a given view. Does anyone know how to do this in MATLAB. What method is the fastest?
 The file with the point cloud contains the coordinates of each point, and information about the color stored in three RGB channels.
First line:

```
`-35.4717 88.8637 -99.3782  97 78 46`
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to re-implement the pipeline of a graphic processor.

Transform your object and project all triangles into an image plane. In this image plane, the distances of each part of the triangle can be stored.
With that information you can check if a vertex is further away than the one you have painted into the image plane.

Comment: I really like this question as I am struggling with this myself.  Just to add to the comment above , what happens in a case where the visible surface is very curvy and overlap. Due to the curviness of the surfaces visible vertex next to each other will vary in distances, would the method above fall short in this case. Kindly elaborate further.